# CSS transitions + absolutely positioned HTML5 video + poster cause flickering

Tags: html5-video, css-transitions, absolute

I have a very specific scenario which I spent a decent amount of time replicating in an MCVE.  As far as I can tell, these are the requirements:

- Something on the page animates using the standard CSS `transition` property (not `transform`)
- The HTML5 video has a `poster` that I provide with a url (the video still generates its own poster from the first frame anyway)
- The video is absolutely positioned (used to [hack a scaleable ratio](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/))

I'm using Chrome 50 on Mac OS, but this issue has been duplicated on Windows.  It does not appear to be an issue in Firefox or Safari on Mac OS.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln4tqxkx/1/) illustrating the problem.  Notice how when you hover over the div that says "Hover," the video switches between my poster and its own auto-generated poster.  This only appears to occur before the video is played.

```css
.anim {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.anim:hover {
  background: black;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#video-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16 x 9 */
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="anim">
  <div>
    Hover
  </div>
</div>
<div id="video-container">
  <video controls poster="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/447374371917922304/P4BzupWu.jpeg">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm">
  </video> 
</div>
```

Why is this happening?  If I can't easily fix this, what would be the best way to maintain the scaleable aspect ratio of a video on a page that has a CSS transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome.  I have submitted a [Chromium bug report (Issue 617642)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617642) in hopes that it will be fixed.

In the meantime, I discovered that this issue only occurs if the element with the transition effect appears earlier in the HTML than the video.  Using `flex-direction: row-reverse` or `flex-direction: column-reverse` I can switch the order of some elements in the HTML and again in the CSS so they appear in the right place but the transition does not affect the video thumbnail.

**UPDATE**: As of Chrome 77, this issue appears to be fixed.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting a similar bug, except mine is flickering multiple times a second. Very strange. This is Chrome: 54.0.2840.50 beta (64-bit) on Mac.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo feel free to add to my big report of it's the same bug or create a new report. Do you have a JSFiddle or a video of the bug?

Answer (score 2):

Such situations with transitions/translates on page you can very often resolve using "magic" `transform: translateZ(0)` for parent or children elements (depends on situation).

In your case it is enough to add this transform to the `#video-container`:

```
#video-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16 x 9 */
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Applied solution [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78s8y52x/)